# Displaying NDEigensystem Results

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh, eigenvalues, solidmechanics

I want to display a collection of deformed meshes in a GraphicsGrid where the surface colors are proportional to the displacement.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[Cuboid[{-0.1, -1, -0.1}, {0.1, 1, 0.1}], 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];

tvars = {{u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, 
   t, {x, y, z}};
pars = <|"Material" -> Entity["Element", "Titanium"]|>;

constraint = SolidFixedCondition[y^2 <= 0.001, tvars, pars];

eigenmodeOperator = 
  SolidMechanicsPDEComponent[tvars, 
   Join[pars, <|"AnalysisType" -> "Eigenmode"|>]];

{evals, evecs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eigenmodeOperator == {0, 0, 0}, constraint}, 
   tvars[[1]], t, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 6];

eigenfrequencies = Re[Sqrt[evals]/(2 Pi)]
```

Here is a picture showing how the coloring should work.

[image]

Comment: Understood, I thought `FaceForm` could take a map maybe using `Texture`. What about using `ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex`?

Comment: There are examples of this in the [solid mechanics monograph](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/SolidMechanics.html#775646651)

Comment: @user21 Can the `NDEigensystem` be computed in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [VectorDisplacementPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorDisplacementPlot3D.html), however, the domain needs to reference the original geometric solid or boundary mesh region (the method I recommend `BoundaryMeshRegion[bar]`), not the element mesh.

```
bar=Cuboid[{-0.1, -1, -0.1}, {0.1, 1, 0.1}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bar, "MeshOrder" -> 1, MeshQualityGoal -> 1]

... PDE ...

plots = Table[
   VectorDisplacementPlot3D[evecs[[i]], {x, y, z} \[Element] bar, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Ticks -> None, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False,
    PlotLabel ->  Style["Freq.=" <> ToString[eigenfrequencies[[i]]] <> " Hz", 12]],
   {i, Length[eigenfrequencies]}];
Grid[Partition[plots, 3]]
```

[image]